# Lotus NotesSQL Driver - cannot install

Tags: windows-xp, drivers, odbc, lotus-notes

I need to install Lotus NotesSQL Driver (current version is 8.5) onto a virtual machine running XP. Here's what's I've done so far:

1. I retrieved the file (`CZOWFEN.zip`) from the IBM website.
2. I ran the exe.
3. I then went to **My Computer**->**Properties**->**Advanced**->**Environmental Settings**->**System Variables**->**Path** and added "`; c:\notessql`" so the ODBC Administrator could find `Notes.ini` (why the setup file didn't do this in the first place, i don't know).
4. I opened up the ODBC Administrator and tried to add a new System DSN to a Lotus DB.

   > "The setup routines for the Lotus Notes SQL Driver (`*.nsf`) ODBC driver could not be loaded due to system error code 126"
5. I redownloaded and reinstalled the driver (making sure I had the latest version 8.5). No luck.
6. I checked the registry. All the file paths appeared to be correct.
7. Per many, many similar cases on the internet, I tried several different variations of adding the various Lotus Notes folders to my `PATH` variables. Same error.

I've done this setup on 5 different machines now with no problem. The only difference here is that this machine is virtual. Ideas?

Comment: What VM software are you running?

Comment: I believe the name is "VMware tools".

Comment: "VMware Virtual Platform"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

was your `notes.ini` located in the `\Lotus\Notes` directory ?

NotesSQL expects to find `Notes.ini` in the `\Lotus\Notes` directory. If
  the file is not in this directory, the driver may crash when you use 
  the ODBC Data Source Administrator to create a DSN, or the NotesSQL 
  Authentication List Manager may report that it is unable to find a 
  valid version of Notes. If you must place `Notes.ini` in a directory 
  other than `\Lotus\Notes`, add the directory to your `PATH` environment 
  variable.

Comment: Adding "C:\Lotus\Notes\" to the PATH environment variable did the trick.

Comment: notes.ini was in C:\Program Files (x86)\Lotus Notes, so I added that to my path and it did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

I found that adding `C:\Program Files\IBM\Lotus\Notes\` (which is what the registry setting `HKLM\Software\Lotus\Notes\Path` points to) to the `PATH` works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Does the NNotes.dll is in the PATH? (if not you need to add it in the path) solved my problem.